# Optimizar sentencias sql consecutivas

Tags: php, pdo

En un código PHP se tiene una serie de UPDATES consecutivos (podrían ser más)

```
$sql= "UPDATE SENTENCIA X";
$sth = $BD->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();

$sql= "UPDATE SENTENCIA Y";
$sth = $BD->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();

$sql= "UPDATE SENTENCIA Z";
$sth = $BD->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();
```

Existe alguna manera de optimizar el proceso de esta ejecución y cuál sería esa forma?

Comment: Pues solamente que en las tablas donde haras tus UPDATE si tienen relación directa que pudieras actualizar todos los campos que necesitas en una sola consulta.

Comment: Viendo que tus sentencias son diferentes: X, Y, Z. Queda claro que lo que pretendes es enviar varias consultas distintas juntas. Poder se puede, pero esto no es compatible con ejecutar **sentencias preparadas**, una práctica esencial para proteger contra la **inyección SQL**. Si es una sola consulta UPDATE puedes pasar un array de valores a tu única sentencia SQL sin  riesgo, pero para varias sentencias tendrías que hacer unos cambios peligrosos a tu configuración PDO. [Ver esta respuesta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346674/pdo-support-for-multiple-queries-pdo-mysql-pdo-mysqlnd)

Answer (score 1):

Si es la misma sentencia pero solo cambian los valores que esta recive, lo mas razonable seria hacer algo así:

```
<?php
/* Se asume la conexión en $BD */

// Creas la consulta
$sql= "UPDATE tabla SET campo=:valor WHERE pk=:pk";

// Preparas una vez
$sth = $BD->prepare($sql);

// Ejecutas tantas como necesites
$sth->execute(array(':valor' => 'valor_1', ':pk' => 'pk_1'));
$sth->execute(array(':valor' => 'valor_2', ':pk' => 'pk_2'));
$sth->execute(array(':valor' => 'valor_3', ':pk' => 'pk_3'));
?>
```